# Can't load application from file /perl/school-reports/script/reports No such file or directory at /usr/local/share/perl/5.34.0/Mojo/Server.pm line 59

Tags: perl, perl-module, mojolicious, cpanm

I am stuck while running the project which has been created on Perl with Mojolicious module. here is the code of the file from where I am running the project using **morbo command**

```
   #!/usr/bin/env perl
    
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    
    use FindBin;
    BEGIN { unshift @INC, "$FindBin::Bin/../lib" }
    use Mojolicious::Commands;
    $ENV{MOJO_USERAGENT_DEBUG} = 1;
    # Start command line interface for application
    Mojolicious::Commands->start_app('Reports');
```

Here is my Reports.pm file --

```
package Reports;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious';
use MongoDB;
use BSON::Types ':all';
use Data::Dumper;

# This method will run once at server start
sub startup {
  my $self = shift;

  my $config = $self->plugin('Config');
  $self->attr(
    db => sub {
      MongoDB->connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/reports');
    }
  );
  $self->helper(
    'db' => sub {
      shift->app->db;
    }
  );
  $self->helper(
    'url' => sub {
      shift->req->url->base->to_string;
    }
  );

  $self->helper(
    user => sub {
      my $self = shift;
      if ($config->{test}) {
        my $user = $self->db->ns('reports.users')->find_id(bson_oid('5e3f1cdcb762464a2d7cde49'));
        return $user;
      }
      if ($self->session->{'sid'}) {
        my $user = $self->db->ns('reports.users')->find_id(bson_oid($self->session->{'user_oid'}));
        if (defined $user) {
          return $user;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    }
  );

  $self->helper(
    active_session => sub {
      my $self = shift;
      return 1 if $config->{test};
      if ($self->session->{'sid'}) {
        my $session = $self->db->ns('reports.sessions')->find_id($self->session->{'sid'});
        return 1 if defined $session;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    }
  );

  # $self->plugin('Status');

  $self->secrets($config->{secrets});

  # Router
  my $r = $self->routes;

  my $auth_route = $r->under('/')->to('login#check_auth');
  my $check_subscription_status = $auth_route->under->to('profile#check_subscription_status');

  my $admin = $auth_route->under(
    '/admin' => sub {
      my $c = shift;

      # Authenticated
      return 1 if $c->user->{admin};

      return 0;

    }
  );

  # my $under = $admin->under('/status')->name('status');
  # $self->plugin('Status' => { route => $under });

  $check_subscription_status->get('/classes')->to('classes#list', section_classes_menu => 1, section_classes => 1)->name('classes');
  $check_subscription_status->get('/classes/archived')->to('classes#archived', section_archived_classes => 1, section_classes_menu => 1)
    ->name('archived_classes');
  $check_subscription_status->get('/classes/new')->to('classes#new_class', id => 0, section_new_class => 1, section_classes_menu => 1)
    ->name('new_class');
  $check_subscription_status->get('/classes/edit/:id')->to('classes#edit', id => 0, section_classes => 1, section_classes_menu => 1)
    ->name('edit_class');
  $auth_route->get('/classes/:class_id/student/:student_id')->to('classes#get_student')->name('get_student');
  $auth_route->post('/classes/save/:id')->to('classes#save', id => 0)->name('save_class');
  $auth_route->get('/classes/archive/:id')->to('classes#save', archive => 1)->name('archive_class');
  $auth_route->get('/classes/restore/:id')->to('classes#save', restore => 1)->name('restore_class');
  $auth_route->post('/classes/csv_import/:id')->to('classes#csv_import')->name('csv_import');

  $auth_route->post('/classes/:id/add_student')->to('classes#add_student')->name('add_student');
  $auth_route->post('/classes/:class_id/save_student/')->to('classes#save_student')->name('save_student');
  $auth_route->post('/classes/:class_id/student/report/:student_id')->to('classes#create_report_for_student')->name('create_report_for_student');

  $auth_route->post('/classes/:class_id/student/report/update/:student_id')->to('classes#update_report_for_student')
    ->name('update_report_for_student');
  $auth_route->post('/classes/:class_id/student/update_rating')->to('classes#update_rating')->name('update_rating');

  $auth_route->post('/classes/:class_id/student/expand')->to('classes#expand_student')->name('expand_student');

  $auth_route->post('/classes/:class_id/student/collapse')->to('classes#expand_student', collapse => 1)->name('collapse_student');

  #$auth_route->get('/classes/:class_id/report/')->to('report#create_report')->name('create_report'); ???

  $auth_route->post('/classes/report/process_ai')->to('classes#process_ai')->name('report_process_ai');

  $auth_route->post('/classes/:class_id/report/:report_id/save_draft')->to('report#save_draft')->name('save_report_draft');

  $admin->get('/subjects/')->to('editor#topics', section_subjects => 1)->name('topics');
  $admin->get('/subjects/new')->to('editor#new_topic', section_subjects => 1)->name('new_topic');
  $admin->get('/subjects/edit/:id')->to('editor#edit_topic', section_subjects => 1)->name('edit_topic');
  $admin->post('/subjects/save/:id')->to('editor#save_topic', id => 0)->name('save_topic');
  $admin->get('/subjects/delete/:id')->to('editor#delete_topic')->name('delete_topic');
  $admin->post('/subjects/import_xls/:id')->to('editor#import_xls')->name('import_xls');

  $admin->get('/subjects/personal_project')->to('editor#personal_project', section_personal_project => 1)->name('personal_project');
  $admin->post('/subjects/personal_project/import_xls')->to('editor#import_xls_personal_project')->name('import_xls_personal_project');


  $admin->get('/templates')->to('templates#list', section_templates => 1)->name('templates');
  $admin->post('/templates/save/:template_id')->to('templates#save')->name('save_template');

  $admin->get('/texts')->to('texts#list', section_texts => 1)->name('texts');
  $admin->post('/texts/save/:text_id')->to('texts#save')->name('save_text');
  $admin->get('/texts/new')->to('texts#new_text')->name('new_text');
  $r->get('/texts/:url')->to('texts#get')->name('get_text');

  $check_subscription_status->get('/profile')->to('profile#index', section_profile => 1)->name('profile');
  $auth_route->post('/profile/update')->to('profile#update')->name('update_profile');
  $auth_route->post('/profile/update_password')->to('profile#update_password')->name('update_password');

  $r->get('/profile/pay/')->to('profile#pay')->name('pay');
  $auth_route->post('/profile/purchase')->to('profile#purchase')->name('purchase');

  $auth_route->post('/profile/subscribe')->to('profile#subscribe')->name('subscribe');
  $auth_route->post('/profile/subscribe/cancel')->to('profile#cancel_subscription')->name('cancel_subscription');
  $r->any('/profile/subscribe/confirm_hook')->to('profile#subscribe_confirm_hook')->name('subscribe_confirm_hook');
  $r->any('/profile/subscribe/cancel_hook')->to('profile#subscribe_cancel_hook')->name('subscribe_cancel_hook');

 # $r->any('/profile/subscribe/confirm_hook_test')->to('profile#subscribe_confirm_hook_test');
  $r->get('/profile/subscribe/confirm')->to('profile#subscribe_confirm_page');
  #$r->get('/profile/subscribe/cancel')->to('profile#subscribe_сancel_page');

  $admin->get('/users')->to('admin#users', section_users => 1)->name('users');
  $admin->get('/')->to('admin#root', section_admin => 1)->name('admin');
  $admin->get('/backups')->to('admin#backups', section_backups => 1)->name('backups');
  $admin->get('/backups/restore/#filename')->to('admin#restore_backup', section_backups => 1)->name('restore_backup');

  $admin->get('/dump')->to('admin#dump')->name('dump');

  $r->get('/')->to('index#index')->name('index');
  $r->get('/register')->to('register#form')->name('register_form');
  $r->post('/register')->to('register#register')->name('register');
  $r->get('/login')->to('login#form')->name('login_form');
  $r->get('/register')->to('register#index')->name('register_form');
  $r->post('/login')->to('login#login')->name('login');
  $r->get('/logout')->to('login#logout')->name('logout');
  $r->post('/login')->to('login#login')->name('login');
  $r->post('/end_session')->to('login#end_session')->name('end_session');

  $r->get('/restore_password')->to('login#restore_password_form')->name('restore_password_form');
  $r->post('/restore_password')->to('login#restore_password')->name('restore_password');

  $r->get('/change_password/:hash')->to('login#change_password_form')->name('change_password_form');
  $r->post('/change_password/:hash')->to('login#change_password')->name('change_password');

  $admin->get('/delete_user/:id')->to('admin#delete_user')->name('delete_user');
  $admin->get('/add_user_credits/:id')->to('admin#add_user_credits')->name('add_user_credits');
  $admin->get('/annulate_user_subscription/:id')->to('admin#annulate_user_subscription')->name('annulate_user_subscription');
  $admin->get('/expire_user_trial/:id')->to('admin#expire_user_trial')->name('expire_user_trial');
  $admin->get('/end_annual_user_subscription/:id')->to('admin#end_annual_user_subscription')->name('end_annual_user_subscription');
  $admin->get('/send_test_email/:id')->to('admin#send_test_email')->name('send_test_email');
  $admin->get('/create_product')->to('admin#create_product')->name('create_product');
  $admin->get('/create_plan')->to('admin#create_plan')->name('create_plan');
  $r->get('/country')->to('register#countries')->name('countries');
  $r->get('/country/check')->to('register#check_country')->name('check_country');
  $r->get('/login/check')->to('register#check_login')->name('check_login');

  $r->get('/contact')->to('contact#form')->name('contact');
  $r->post('/contact/send')->to('contact#send_contact_message')->name('send_contact_message');

  # git
  $admin->get(
    '/git' => sub {
      my $self = shift;
      `cd /home/school-reports;git pull origin master;ubic restart reports;`;
    }
  )->name('git');
};
```

All modules has been installed successfully and trying to run the project using morbo command. I am getting the error while running the project. Not sure why even each module and files are there. also Server.pm file is there in the specified path.

Please help me to run this project. The project is in Perl and ep templates for CPAN. Please confirm what I am missing to run the project.

Comment: *"Mojolicious::Commands->start_app('Reports')"* : Can you also show the source code for `Reports.pm` ? See [mcve] for more information

Comment: Perhaps you don't have a File `Reports.pm` in your lib directory? Check  for typos (case matters) .  In `Mojo/Server.pm`  you can edit line 57 to end with: `do \$path or die $@ ";`  so you get a better error message.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I have edited the question. Please check.

Comment: Can't load application from file "/var/www/html/perl/school-reports/script/reports": Configuration file "/var/www/html/perl/school-reports/script/../reports.conf" missing, maybe you need to create it?
 ...propagated at (eval 140) line 1.

This is the error it showing after adding the line

Comment: Thank you guys. reports.conf file was missing. I added it and it working. Thank you so much really.

Comment: There is a commit on github dating from last week that improves the error message. So this will surely be fixed in the next Mojolicious release.